# While working on codemirror even though i have it in my package json i am getting this error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, codemirror

```
import "codemirror/lib/codemirror.css";
import "codemirror/theme/material.css";
import 'codemirror/mode/xml/xml.js'
import 'codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js'
import 'codemirror/mode/css/css.js'
```

Module not found: Error: Package path ./lib/codemirror.css is not exported from package
the same error for all the import.

I was just trying to get my output for the editor component.

Comment: As the error tells you, the package does not allow these files to be imported. Probably those are internal files which are not supposed to be directly used by developers. Why do you need to import those files?

Answer (score 0):

i think there is some issue with the codemirror files. May be because they dont export any thing directly due to which these import statements are not able to pull anything from those addresses. if some one finds a way to import those please suggest any other ways to import those features from codemirror

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).